# Montgomery Reduction - Conditions on R

Tags: montgomery-multiplication

In Montgomery Reduction, we need to compute $z = x y \text{ mod  } N$ and the Montgomery Reduction of $x$ is $xR^{-1}$.

- Why should the choice of $R$ be $2^l$ where $l$ is the length of $N$ to the base $2$?
- Why cannot we have a larger $R$?

This is a cross question with [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982620/montgomery-reduction-what-should-the-choice-of-r-be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, The [Montgomery's Reduction](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777282-X/S0025-5718-1985-0777282-X.pdf) algorithm requires that $\operatorname{GCD}(n,R)=1$ .
This requirement is satisfied iff $n$ is odd.

The $R$ is chosen as $2^l$ where $ 2^{l-1} \leq n < 2^{l}$.

For $x < n$  the $n$-residue with respect to $R$ is defined as;

$$ x' = x \cdot r \bmod n$$ than the set

$$\{i \cdot R \bmod n\;|\; 0 \leq i \leq n-1 \}$$ is a complete residue system, that is, it contains all the numbers between $0$ and $n-1$.

The selection of $R$ is the smallest bound.

> - Why should the choice of $R$ be $2^l$ where $l$ is the length of $N$ to the base $2$?

Montgomery Reduction converts arbitrary division into shift operations. Therefore  $2^l$  is a good choice for computers, we have to shift $l$ bits.

> - Why cannot we have a larger $R$?

It won't be effective since you will have more unnecessary shiftings due to a larger $R$.

**note:** if $R<n$ than this will not work.

Comment: Do you mean $2^l$ instead of $n^l?$